# Connection Problem in mongodb 4.2.8 on AWS ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created new Instance on AWS ec2 and installed the mongodb 4.2.8 on server but I'm unable to connect with mongodb using local terminal of Ubuntu 18.0.2. I'm hitting a command which will import a mongodb dump database into the server database the command is given below

```
mongorestore --host IPv4_Public_IP --port 27017 --db db_name dump/dataDb/
```

The error I'm facing is

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: IPv4_Public_IP:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp IPv4_Public_IP:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

And how to set the Inboud rules for that instance. For now these are

`SSH    TCP       22    0.0.0.0/0   -`

`Custom TCP       27017 my_ip   -`

Comment: Are you able to SSH to the host ?

Comment: Yeah using this command I'm able to access SSH `ssh -i "abc.pem" ubuntu@ec2-IPv4_Public_IP.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` @ChrisWilliams